# NVM memory data change without software intervention

Tags: embedded

Is there any chance that data in  NVM memory can be altered without sw intervention?if it is possible in what situation data can alter?

Thanks,
Raju

Comment: Way too vague a question. What type of nonvolatile memory? What embedded system? The short answer is: **YES**. Anything from a hardware error, gamma rays, a debug port, etc. Without more information, it's impossible to give you better answer.

Comment: No. The razor-sharp edge of Occam’s razor is gleaming at you in the sunshine. The most obvious reason for NVM value to change or be ‘wrong’ is that software has changed it in a way you don’t expect/assume. Maybe you didn’t read the value correctly, maybe you didn’t write correctly, maybe some other part of the software changed the NVM value while you weren’t watching, but Occam says that software writes to NVM and your software is the reason why the value you are seeing is not what you expect. Or a hardware problem.

Comment: Either this is an X-Y problem, or off-topic/too broad.  If you are seeing unexplained changes to NV data, something is causing it, and it is more likely to be software (either by design or error) that is changing it that any other cause, and you should ask about the specific issue rather than posting a generic question about the _possibility_.  Yes it is possible (but unlikely), but that does not help you much does it?  If it is just a generic question, it is too broad and off-topic, and not even specific enough about the NVM technology involved.

Comment: @daShier : Where the memory is changed via a debug port, presumably that debug port is driven by software, so strictly that is not "without software intervention", even if that software is running on the development host rather then the embedded target.

Comment: @barny : I like the razor-sharp edge of your wit!  However Ocaam's Razor does not assign zero probability to all the unlikely possibilities, so "No" may be too emphatic.  If Raju is looking for an excuse as to why his system is not working however, he is _most_ probably looking in the wrong place and his software is at fault.  He should be asking about the problem, not the theoretical possibility that his software is perfect - that _is_ very unlikely!

Comment: @Clifford, You are spot on. I should have been more clear and stated that the scenarios I described simply answer the OP as the question was stated, rather than giving the most likely reason for seeing values changing. Of course, _probable_ is a very different question than _possible_.

Comment: Data retention is real. Among the products I maintain, some are terribly old, 25-30 years. Their EEPROM is occasionally going bananas after such a long time and software has nothing to do with it.